# Multiple consecutive lines on the same plot matplotlib with different x labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot two different consecutive lines on the same graph with two different xlabel. My code at the moment is

```
plt.xlabel('\\# Basis')
plt.ylabel('Energy')
plt.grid(True)
plt.plot(np.arange(1,size_basis+1), means_SGD, label='SGD step')
plt.fill_between(np.arange(1,size_basis+1), max_SGD, min_SGD, alpha=0.5)
plt.legend()

plt.xlabel('\\# Step')
plt.xticks(np.arange(10,59), np.arange(1, 50))
plt.plot(np.arange(10, 59), means_s, label='SGD full')
plt.fill_between(np.arange(10, 59), max_v_s, min_v_s, alpha=0.5)
plt.legend()
```

And I got the following output

[Output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF3Bb.png)

However I would like to have something like

[What I would like to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMnLB.png)

Clearly with the grid in the first part of the graph also.

Thanks for help

```
plt.xlabel('\\# Basis')
plt.ylabel('Energy')
plt.grid(True)
plt.plot(np.arange(1,size_basis+1), means_SGD, label='SGD step')
plt.fill_between(np.arange(1,size_basis+1), max_SGD, min_SGD, alpha=0.5)
plt.legend()

plt.xlabel('\\# Step')
plt.xticks(np.arange(10,59), np.arange(1, 50))
plt.plot(np.arange(10, 59), means_s, label='SGD full')
plt.fill_between(np.arange(10, 59), max_v_s, min_v_s, alpha=0.5)
plt.legend()
```

[Output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF3Bb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by placing text using `annotate`, but the text should be placed outside the axes. I'm sure there is a way to do this elegantly using transforms, but I'm not familiar enough with transforms. For now, here is a way to do this with manually placing the text.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

plt.close("all")

x0 = 1
xn = 50
xswitch = 10
N = 100
xl = np.linspace(x0, xswitch, N)
xr = np.linspace(xswitch, xn, N)

yl = 1/xl**0.6
yr = 1/xr**0.6

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax.plot(xl, yl, label="SGD step")
ax.plot(xr, yr, label="SGD full")

ax.set_ylabel("Energy")
ax.set_xlabel("")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
ax.grid()
ax.legend()
ax.set_aspect(20)
ax.annotate("# Basis", xy=(0.5*(x0+xswitch), -0.1), annotation_clip=False)
ax.annotate("# Step", xy=(0.5*(xswitch+xn), -0.1), annotation_clip=False)
```

[image]

### Improvement on Matt's Answer

To improve on @[Matt Pitkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1862861/matt-pitkin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76858432/12131013), you can use `sharey=True` to avoid having to match up the y ticks manually. I would also use the major tick locator to not show all the x-ticks.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

# some mock data
N = 60
x = np.arange(1, N)
data = 1 / x**0.6

Nstart = 10  # define the index to switch between plots

# width ratios of plots
ratios = [Nstart / N, (N - Nstart) / N]

# define with subplots with no space inbetween
fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    1,
    2,
    gridspec_kw={"wspace": 0, "width_ratios": ratios},
    figsize=(12, 4),
    sharey=True
)

# remove borders from parts of plot (right border from left
# plot and left border from right plot)
ax[0].spines["right"].set_visible(False)
ax[1].spines["left"].set_visible(False)
ax[1].tick_params(axis="y", which="both", length=0)  # remove y-ticks

# plot on the left plot
l1, = ax[0].plot(x[:Nstart + 1], data[:Nstart + 1], color="tab:blue", label="SGD step")
ax[0].set_xlabel("# Basis")

# plot on the right plot
l2, = ax[1].plot(x[Nstart:], data[Nstart:], color="tab:orange", label="SGD full")
ax[1].set_xlabel("# Step")

# set the x limits on both plots so that things join up
ax[0].set_xlim([x[0], x[Nstart]])
ax[1].set_xlim([x[Nstart], x[-1]])

for _ax in ax:
    _ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
    _ax.grid()

ax[1].legend(handles=[l1, l2])

fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. It actually works with a slight modification. Since I want the xlabels restart from one in the second graph I added `ax[0].set_xticks(x[Nstart,N], x[1:N-Nstart])`. Thanks again.

Comment: @PaoloRecchia Great. You can accept one of the answers to your question by clicking the gray check next to that solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've mocked up something that you could try. The basic idea is rather than using one plot, you do two side-by-side subplots and remove the space in between.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# some mock data
N = 60
x = np.arange(1, N)
data = 1 / x**0.6

Nstart = 10  # define the index to switch between plots

# width ratios of plots
ratios = [Nstart / N, (N - Nstart) / N]

# define with subplots with no space inbetween
fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    1,
    2,
    gridspec_kw={"wspace": 0, "width_ratios": ratios},
    figsize=(12, 4)
)

# remove borders from parts of plot (right border from left
# plot and left border from right plot)
ax[0].spines["right"].set_visible(False)
ax[1].spines["left"].set_visible(False)
ax[1].tick_params(axis="y", which="both", length=0)  # remove y-ticks

# plot on the left plot
l1, = ax[0].plot(x[:Nstart + 1], data[:Nstart + 1], color="tab:blue", label="SGD step")
ax[0].set_xlabel("# Basis")
ylim1 = ax[0].get_ylim()

# plot on the right plot
l2, = ax[1].plot(x[Nstart:], data[Nstart:], color="tab:orange", label="SGD full")
ax[1].set_xlabel("# Step")

# try and set y-ticks on right band plot (to allow grid to be drawn)
ax[1].set_yticks(ax[0].get_yticks(), [])

ylim2 = ax[1].get_ylim()

# make sure y limits are the same on both plots
ytop = max(ylim1[1], ylim2[1])
ybot = min(ylim1[0], ylim2[0])
ax[0].set_ylim([ybot, ytop])
ax[1].set_ylim([ybot, ytop])

# set the x limits on both plots so that things join up
ax[0].set_xlim([x[0], x[Nstart]])
ax[1].set_xlim([x[Nstart], x[-1]])

# set xlabels
ax[0].set_xticks(x[:Nstart], x[:Nstart])
ax[1].set_xticks(x[Nstart:], x[Nstart:])

# set grids on
ax[0].grid(True)
ax[1].grid(True)

ax[1].legend(handles=[l1, l2])

fig.tight_layout()

fig.show()
```

This gives:

[image]

As you can see, the y-grid on the right-hand plot still isn't consistent with the left hands one, so will require some adjusting (comments welcome!).

Comment: I added an improved version of your solution.